# precise meaning of connected manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

what does it mean for a manifold to be "connected" precisely?

what is the difference between a connected riemannian manifold and a nonconnected one. (i know what a riemannian manifold is a manifold equipped with riemannian metric)

Comment: I cannot understand your question. There is nothing special about a metric in a non-connected manifold

Comment: I don't understand it either. It's just a topology thing, nothing special for manifolds compared to normal topological spaces.

Comment: Trivial example: an open ball is a connected manifold. The union of two (or more) disjoint open balls is a non-connected manifold. The general case is similar, a disconnected manifold is the disjoint union of open parts that are connected manifolds. (Everything needs to have the same dimension, of course, else the union isn't a manifold.)

Answer (score 0):

A topological space is connected if you cannot realize it as the union of two disjoint nonempty open subsets.